# How to read LSB bits using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, steganography

I have been working on steganography, in which I am trying to read the LSB bit of every byte and store in database. Please help me out how to read LSB bit using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Just use bitwise operator. To read LSB from image data

```
int msgbit= msgChar & 1;
```

If you want to set the LSB:

```
msgChar=msgChar & 254;
msgChar=msgChar+newbit;
```

Answer (score 1):

[LSB Stegnography Project in c#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stegtool/)

This is a project which i did for 24bitmap LSB stegnography in C# you can take some idea from this